# simple fetch api example not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm new in react-native,Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

class FetchExample extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            date: ''
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch("http://date.jsontest.com/")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                console.log('a');
                this.setState({date: responseData.date});
            })
            .done();
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ak', () => FetchExample);
```

**And here is the log Error:**

> 10:53:38 PM: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `AwakeInDevApp`.
>       in AwakeInDevApp (at registerRootComponent.js:36)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:113)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:113)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:126)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
>   - node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33:20 in printWarning
>   - ... 24 more stack frames from framework internals

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to export your component. like this

```
export default class FetchExample extends Component {
```